# z-index not working only with fullPage.js

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I have the following one page setup with one container and 3 divs. I have set a :before div for each of the 3 div for parallax effect and set the z-index accordingly so that the div with  text overlaps the :before div with the background image. All is working correctly, **until i insert the jquery plugin fullPage.js.**

At that point, it seems the z-index is not working properly as the :before div is overlapping the div with  text.

I suspect there might be a conflict with jquery.fullPage.css which is found below. *Any ideas?*

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

enter code here html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2b632;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100vh);
}

.bio {
  background-color: #252839;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #f2b632;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

bio>h1 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.bio:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-image: url(../images/logo1.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.photos {
  background-color: #677077;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.photos>h1 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.photos:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-image: url(../images/logo1.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.contact {
  background-color: #f2b632;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #252839;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.contact>h1 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.contact:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-image: url(../images/logo1.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .bio,
  .photos,
  .contact {
    font-size: 1.6em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .bio,
  .photos,
  .contact {
    font-size: 2.7em;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Parallax Effect</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/parallax-js.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="fullpage" class="container">
    <div class="section bio ">
      <h1>My name is Leo. I am a beginner freelance web developer based in Toronto, Canada.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section photos">
      <h1>Let me build you a website.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section contact">
      <h1>Contact me</h1>
      <div>
        <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-5x"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-at fa-5x"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        scrollBar: true
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding position: relative with z-index: 2 to the section divs, along with setting z-index: -1 to div::before.

```
.bio {
background-color: #252839;
font-size: 1em;
color: #f2b632;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
padding: 0 30px;
}

.bio:before {
content: ' ';
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
opacity: 0.1;
background-image: url(../images/logo1.svg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```